# Can not build APK file with buildozer. UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: android, compiler-errors, buildozer

When I am pack my app with Buildozer for Android, I get an `UnicodeDecodeError`. Log2 is attached together with Buildozer **build.py**.

OS: UBUNTU 16.04.

I am trying on python 2.7 and 3.5, get same error.

Link with files: https://yadi.sk/d/F76tP019ZAKRLA

Comment: Move the code and error to the question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from buildozer Pypi! Problem was in the app name!!! Verbos irregulares en Español. After replacing ñ by n, I got my apk! I almost destroy my Ubuntu trying to fix this bug!)

Answer (score 0):

buildozer cant support apk file now.
u must use earlier version of that and i notice that it MAYBE work and